# Rclick registry run java program

Tags: java, registry

I run my java program in command linewith this statement

```
java myclass -a filetype.txt
```

But I want to run my program with right-click on a file with manipulating shell registry, but i don't what should write in shell default value

e.g for adding an option right-click to run with command prompt in windows, I set the default value with `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe`

but don't know how can run my java program with a simple right click.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you right, you want to right click on `filetype.txt` and run your java class on it?!

To achieve that you could do the following steps:

- create a batch file (e.g. `run.cmd`) with the following content:

  ```
  java -cp C:\path\to\myclass myclass -a %1
  ```
- create a registry key bellow `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell` (or `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.txt\shell` if you want to apply your prog only to txt files)
- name it what you want, and give it a value of your choice. This value will be what you see in your context menu
- create another key bellow the recently created one and name it `command`
- give it the value `C:\path\to\run.cmd %1`

that did the trick for me. If you don't like the additional `*.cmd` file, put

```
cmd /c java -cp C:\path\to\myclass myclass -a %1
```

as the value for the `command` key. And remember to use double quotes for paths that contain whitespaces.

Comment: Maybe you can put it directly into `command` if you use the full `java.exe` path? Like `C:\Program Files\Java\jre<something>\bin\java.exe`?

Comment: I tried putting `"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe"` as command, but that raised an access denied error. Now I tried the absolute path of my jre and it worked. Maybe `%JAVA_HOME%` is not present in the registry.

Comment: Sometimes it's set as `%JRE_HOME%`, sometimes it just isn't set (by the installers, I mean).